# Shortcut for starting an application in current tag or if already started bring to current tag in awesome wm

Tags: awesome-wm

I would like to have keyboard shortcut for starting my password manager in the current tag, or if it's already started to bring it to my current tag.

I'm sure it is possible but I can't seem to find a starting point on how to do this.

Comment: Does https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html#raise_or_spawn do what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and report back when I managed to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the following code

```
awful.key({modkey }, "]", function()
        local rule = { class = "keepassxc" }
        local c = awful.spawn.raise_or_spawn("keepassxc", rule)
        for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
            if awful.rules.match(c, rule) then
                client.focus = c
                c:move_to_tag(client.focus.screen.tags[awful.tag.getidx()])
                return
            end
        end
    end, {description = "run keepass", group = "launcher"}),
```

thanks @uli-schlachter for the tip.

Comment: You can use `if c.class == "keepassxc" then` rather than rules. This would make the code simpler. Also `client.focus.screen.tags[awful.tag.getidx()]` can be simplified to `awful.screen.focused().selected_tag`